# useQuery runs 4 times instead of 1 and then stops with an error message, in react

Tags: reactjs, axios, react-custom-hooks, tanstackreact-query

I'm using useQuery inside a custom hook, called usePostData. this is the custom hook code:

```
import { useQuery } from "@tanstack/react-query";
import axios from "axios";

const usePostData = (queryKey, endPoint, object) =>
  useQuery(
    [queryKey],
    async () => {
      await axios
        .post("http://localhost:1337" + endPoint, object)
        .then((data) => console.log(data, queryKey))
        .catch((err) => console.log(err));
      return data;
    },
    { enabled: false }
  );

export default usePostData;
```

I'm calling it on a submit event of a form, like this:

```
  const { data: response, refetch } = usePostData(
    `postSingularExpense-${Math.random()}`,
    "/api/expences",
    submittedExpense
  );

  const handleSubmitExpense = async (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    await refetch();
  };
```

for some reason, it runs 4 times instead of once and thenm stops with this error message:

[error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AHZ3s.png)

why is that and how to correct it?

Answer (score 0):

- You're referring to `data` outside of the function where it exists
- `await axios.post().then()` doesn't make sense. If you're using `await` on a function, it will return resolved value so you don't need `.then()`. Use `async/await` *or* promise syntax, not both

```
const usePostData = (queryKey, endPoint, object) =>
  useQuery(
    [queryKey],
    async () => {
      try {
        const { data } = await axios.post("http://localhost:1337" + endPoint, object);
        console.log(data, queryKey);
        return data;
      }
      catch(err) {
        console.log(err)
      }
    },
    { enabled: false }
  );
```

Also, I noticed your query key: `postSingularExpense-${Math.random()}`. What is that? If you want to force a refetch you should't need to randomize the key.

`useQuery()` returns function `retry()` and includes options like `refetchOnMount`, `refetchInterval` etc. You should look into using one of those approaches instead.

Answer (score 0):

The data variable inside your useQuery callback is not defined, (block scope) which leads to the ReferenceError you're receiving.

Solve it by removing the `await` and `.then()`s :)

You need to capture the response data returned by the POST request and return it from the callback function.

In addition, you're generating a random query key for each request, which causes a new query to be created every time. Instead, you should use a better, more stable, query key, such as the endpoint or a unique identifier for the resource you're posting.

The updated code is:

```
import { useQuery } from "@tanstack/react-query";
import axios from "axios";

const usePostData = (queryKey, endPoint, object) =>
  useQuery(queryKey, async () => {
    try {
      const { data } = await axios.post("http://localhost:1337" + endPoint, object);
      console.log(data, queryKey);
      return data;
    } catch (error) {
      console.log(error);
      throw error;
    }
  }, { enabled: false });

export default usePostData;
```